# How to post a comment without refreshing the page.,

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want a user to be able to post a comment without the browser refreshing the whole page,

For now the comment gets submitted but the problem that I am facing is that, after a user submits a comment the page and whatever the user has put in the form remains there, I want it to get submitted properly and also the users input should clear out once the form has been successfully submitted.

**my controller action**

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)


    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
        respond_to do |format|
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully created a comment"
            format.json { render json: @post }
        end
    else
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

**My View**

```
<div class="header-wrapper-blog">
  <div class="heading_for_blog">
    <div class="container">
      <%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true, :html => {:multipart => true, id: "newcomment"  } ) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :body, as: :text %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="comment-form" name="submit"/>Submit</button>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My current Ajax code**

```
$(function(){
  $("#newcomment").on("submit", function(event){


  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: this.action,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        //update the DOM
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using `remote: true`, then no need to trigger another ajax event, which you are doing.
So now you would have two cases, A.With `remote: true` B.With triggering  Ajax.

Remove `format.json { render json: @post }` line from your controller and rails will render a file `create.js.erb` inside your respective controller views.In that file you can write logic to clear that form or update particular div.
For Ex. `$(#newcomment).reset();` and you can update a div also like `$(#div).html("blah");`

B.if you remove `remote: true` from your form then you can use ajax, which you have mentioned but in that case add `dataType: script` and it will render same `create.js.erb`.

C.If you dont want to follow above approaches then you can call this line `$(#newcomment).reset();` in your success callback of ajax;